# In Nodejs (request) how to send file in a mutliPart http request

Tags: node.js, http, curl, request

How can I send File using MultiPart using from Nodejs, using request?

That will be the same as following command to Curl:

```
curl -X POST -F "photos[]=@img.jpg;type=image/jpg" https://example.com
```

The Http request it creates:

```
{
  "json": null,
  "files": {
    "photos[]": "data:image/jpg;base64,[Binary]
},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------0195fbe0d4ab",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "Content-Length": "42311",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8x zlib/1.2.5"
  },
  "origin": "23.125.128.191",
  "data": "",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post",
  "args": {}
}
```

Comment: A simple search for 'nodejs multipart form data' revealed this: https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data. Remember: Node.js already has a ton of OS modules readily available, only a search away!

Comment: @SimonPlus you should probably submit that comment as an answer, and mention one of the examples from the README

Answer (score 2):

A simple search for 'nodejs multipart form data' revealed this: [github.com/felixge/node-form-data](http://github.com/felixge/node-form-data). It even works with the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module:

```
var FormData = require('form-data');
var request = require('request');

var form = new FormData();

form.append('photos[]', request('img.jpg'));

form.submit('https://example.com/', function(err, res) {
    res.resume(); // for node-0.10.x
});
```

Remember: Node.js already has a ton of OS modules readily available, only a search away!

Comment: `res.resume();` saves me hours of debugging after upgrading my project to 0.10